# Why does renaming an HTML element remove its events?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I've noticed that when I change the ID or name of a form element via JavaScript, the jQuery events that were tied to it are no longer there. I've tried this with Firefox 17 and IE 10. Is this by design? And if so, is there any way to prevent it?

**UPDATE:** Please check http://jsfiddle.net/qHH7P/2/ for an example.

I'm adding the button to remove the row via jQuery. When I remove the first row, I give the elements in the second row a new name and ID. Then the remove button for that remaining row doesn't fire the event anymore. I need to rename the elements because ASP.NET MVC expects a certain naming convention for the collection of objects when binding. That's why I need to rename them with a "0" instead of "1". I'm doing my rename with

```
var regexpattern = new RegExp("WorkspaceQuestionSets\\[.+\\]", "g");
$(this).html($(this).html().replace(regexpattern, "WorkspaceQuestionSets[" + index + "]"));
var regexpattern = new RegExp("WorkspaceQuestionSets_.+__", "g");
$(this).html($(this).html().replace(regexpattern, "WorkspaceQuestionSets_" + index + "__"));
```

I just realized that I'm not even renaming the buttons. So it makes even less sense that the event is gone. But if I comment out the code to rename the elements, the event remains.

Comment: Please post your code. Changing attributes does not remove event handlers. Rewriting the HTML would though.

Comment: Does this happen even if the jquery selector used when attaching the event is CSS based and not ID based? Can you work around this by not changing the ID or name?

Comment: Are you talking about "live" events? Like `$(document).on('click', '#foo', handler)`? These will stop triggering if the element falls out of the selector (such as changing its `id`, in this example). If you use normal event handlers, renaming shouldn't matter.

Comment: @FelixKling - I'm working to simplify my scenario and will post the code shortly.

Comment: Be free don't use jquery for basic things

Comment: @dlamblin - The events are bound to elements with a specific class..not the ID. I don't think I can get around renaming the elements because I'm using ASP.NET MVC and need the element names to be sequential so they properly bind to my collection of objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are rewriting the HTML. `.html()` returns a **string**, which you then modify and set again. The browser will parse that HTML string and create new DOM elements from it. In this process, your destroying DOM elements and consequently loose the event handlers you bound to them before.

> I just realized that I'm not even renaming the buttons. So it makes even less sense that the event is gone.

You are destroying and recreating every single element that is inside `this` (each row I assume), no matter whether you modified its HTML representation or not.

---

You have to possibilites to solve this:

1. Use event delegation: Instead of binding the event handlers directly to the elements, bind them to an ancestor, which will always exist. Read more about event delegation in the [`.on` *<sup>[docs]</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/on/) documentation, section *Direct and delegated events*.
2. Don't rewrite the HTML. Select the elements whose `name` attribute you want to modify and modify it. For example:

   ```
   var name_exp1 = /WorkspaceQuestionSets\[.+\]/g;
   var name_exp2 = /WorkspaceQuestionSets_.+__/g;


   sourceEle.closest(".table").find(".row.set").each(function(index) {
       // Edit the name attribute of all `select` and `input` elements
       $(this).find('select, input').prop('name', function(i, name) {
           if (name_exp1.test(name)) {
               return name.replace(
                   name_exp1, 
                   "WorkspaceQuestionSets[" + index + "]"
               );
           }
           else if (name_exp2.test(name)) {
               return name.replace(
                   name_exp1, 
                   "WorkspaceQuestionSets_" + index + "__"
               );
           }
           return name;
       });
   });
   ```

In JavaScript, forget the HTML and work with the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

This does not happen to me with plain JavaScript in Chrome 24.

Here's what I typed in the JS console:

```
document.write("<button id='bb'/>")
//undefined
var bb=document.getElementById('bb')
//undefined
bb
//<button id=​"bb">​</button>​
bb.addEventListener('click',function(){alert('hi');});
//undefined
bb
//<button id=​"bb">​</button>​
bb.id
//"bb"
bb.id="qq"
//"qq"
bb
//<button id=​"qq">​</button>​
document.getElementById("bb")
//null
document.getElementById("qq")
//<button id=​"qq">​</button>​
```

And importantly clicking the button made the event trigger both before and after the assignment to `bb.id`.

Also in Firefox 17 I didn't quite see that happening with plain JavaScript. I was on the page: http://start.ubuntu.com/12.04/Google/?sourceid=hp

And in the console here's what I issued:

```
[19:29:41.261] var bb=document.getElementById('sbtn')
[19:29:41.267] undefined
[19:29:45.501] bb.addEventListener('click',function(){alert('hi')});
[19:29:45.507] undefined
[19:29:48.292] bb.id
[19:29:48.298] "sbtn"
[19:29:59.613] bb.id="sbttttttn"
[19:29:59.619] "sbttttttn"
```

The alert still occurred after the `id` was changed.

This must be specific to either IE, which I cannot try, or the way jQuery sets up events or handles ID changes (perhaps invisibly destroying the object?).

Comment: Hmm..tested my code in Chrome 23 and events still go missing. I'll get my code up asap.